# Minimal number of lines in $\sf{PG}(2, n)$ to guarantee 3 are concurrent?

Tags: combinatorics, projective-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

I am trying to figure out the least number of lines which guarantees that 3 will meet at the same point in a projective plane of order $n$. Through experimentation with $n=2$ and $3$ I get (unless I have overlooked something) $5$ and $6$ respectively. This is essentially by drawing pairs of parallel lines of varying 'gradients' till it seems a new line would cross a previous intersection. With $n+k$ lines we have $\frac{1}{2}(n+k)(n+k-1)$ intersections amongst $n^2+n+1$ possibilities, but I am having a hard time arguing what the pattern here is and why.

Is there a nice intuitive answer to this question?

**edit** for what it's worth, this question came about because in the game Spot It! (i.e. ${\sf {PG}(2,7)}$ with $2$ points removed) there is a variation which involves placing $9$ cards on the table and having players trying to find a three-way match (1 symbol on three cards). The value of $9$ is one lower than the 'easy bound', which got me wondering whether it is indeed a guarantee or not.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the first line $\ell$ arbitrarily.  How many lines can you add before *some point on $\ell$* belongs to at least three lines?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! This reasoning gives the $n+3$ as sufficient, I guess what I'm not sure on yet is whether it is necessary? I can't seem to get a nice reliable construction which takes an $\ell$, draws a line through each of its points, and guarantees no 3 are crossing elsewhere.